# How to use services in custom pipes in angular 2

Tags: angular2-services, angular2-pipe

I want to display months in years on html. My filter takes number of months as an input and it should return years.

For example: if it takes 12 as input, it should return translated value as 1 year. and if it is more than 1 year, it should return '2 years'.

my pipe contains:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name : 'displayMonthsInYears '})
export class DisplayMonthsInYears implements PipeTransform{
    transform(noOfMonths : number) : any {
         if(noOfMonths > 12){
            return (noOfMonths / 12 + $translate.instace('YEARS'));
         }
         return (noOfMonths / 12 + $translate.instace('YEAR'));
    }
}
```

and html is :

```
 <div class="text-left">
     {{ contractDuration | displayMonthsInYears }}
 </div>
```

I don't have a clue how to make that happen. Please help.

Comment: I am a bit skeptical with this `$translate.instace('YEARS')`, but other than that it seems like there's nothing wrong with your code, what's your error? Is it your pipe doesn't work or your goal (display months in years) is not yet achieved?

Comment: $translate is not present in angular 2. We need to import import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core'; and use it. I don't know how to use :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the translate lib and its http-loader with

```
npm install @ngx-translate/core @ngx-translate/http-loader --save
```

**Follow the set up guide in the `@ngx-translate` docs**. Then import the service:

```
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';
```

Inject it into your pipe and use it like this:

```
@Pipe({name : 'displayMonthsInYears '})

export class DisplayMonthsInYears implements PipeTransform{

  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {}

  transform(noOfMonths : number) : any {

     if (noOfMonths > 12) {
        return (noOfMonths / 12 + this.translate.instant('YEARS'));
     }

     return (noOfMonths / 12 + this.translate.instant('YEAR'));
  }
}
```

`instant` will return the value straight away, there's also useful ones such as `stream` which will give you an observable which will keep streaming the value to your subscriptions even when the language changes. Which `get` won't. There's more methods you can use so I'd suggest you look in the docs and learn which suits you the best.